# Design pattern for sitewide configuration in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to set some user preferences in my angular app. I will get these preference from a REST api so I will need to make a http call. Once these have been fetched from the API, their values will not be modified.

What is the best practice in this case?

Can I make http calls in [angular.module.value](http://www.learn-angular.org/#!/lessons/the-value-recipe)? Or use something like a [provider](http://www.learn-angular.org/#!/lessons/the-provider-recipe)? Or just write a service? What are the things to consider in any of these approaches?

What is the design pattern to be followed in this case?

Comment: Important question here is when gyou will use these preference, during the angular app bootstrap process?

Comment: I want to use these values on application load. So, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a service using the factory recipe. That will make the code a lttle cleaner and more modular.

Following that, you could put the user preferences on the $rootScope. This is a good case for a valid use of $rootScope, since your values are constants with application-wide applicability.

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a try.